# How to create info button in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

How can i create info button on the right side for editing the content along with the deletion control(left side) whenever i click edit button?

[image]

(something like this)

`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use accessoryType.

In cellForRowAt method, add

```
    cell.editingAccessoryType = .detailButton
```

and Give action to it by

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Accessory btn tapped")
    }
```